# How to combine children meshes before run-time in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have created an empty game object and its the parent of many different objects that have meshes. I am wondering if there is any way of combining the meshes before run-time so I can have a saved mesh so i can use for colliders, or for creating an outline of all the objects combined rather than making an out line of each individual one.

I was looking at [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/combine-children-extented-sources-to-share.37721/), but it does not seem to be working for Unity 2017.2.x because it seems like MeshCombineUtility no longer is part of the standard assets.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may encounter this same question in the future.
[Mesh Combiner](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mesh-combine-wizard-free-unity-tool-source-code.444483/)